# Comment dire "Enterprise File Synchronization and Sharing" (EFSS) en français ?

Tags: traduction, informatique, abréviations

EFSS (Enterprise File Synchronization and Sharing) est le domaine des logiciels permettant aux employés de synchroniser, partager and collaborer sur des documents/photos/vidéos/fichiers avec leur collègues ou clients.

Utilisation en anglais:

> Today's EFSS market offers a range of maturing options to IT leaders as well as mobile and collaboration planners. New capabilities for corporate system integration and enhanced content collaboration continue to add to standard EFSS functionality. *(Gartner)*
>
> Companies should look for an EFSS vendor that offers not only top-notch encryption but should consider choosing an on-premises, as opposed to pure or hybrid cloud, if they have issues with comingling data with others.

**QUESTION:** L'EFSS est une vaste industrie, donc je suis sûr qu'un terme existe aussi en français, mais quel est-il? Avec quel abréviation ?

---

Mon essai:

- "SPFE": Synchronisation et Partage de Fichiers d'Entreprise (mais aucun résultat avec ce sens dans les 5 premières pages de Google pour "SPFE")

[Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_(entreprise)) emploie (sans références) cette expression:

> [...] est nommé "Leader" dans l’étude Magic Quadrant (2014), concernant la synchronisation et le partage de fichiers en entreprise.

[Ricoh Canada](http://rcloudservices.ricoh.ca/fr-ca/solutions/synchronisation-et-partage-de-fichiers-pour-entreprises.html) tente ceci (voir par ailleurs leur "nuagiciel"):

> Synchronisation et partage de fichiers pour entreprises

Answer (score 3):

Le plus naturel serait **Système de fichiers partagés ou répliqués**.

remarque 1: le partage / la synchronisation sont des raffinements qui vont souvent de pair.

remarque 2: en français, on omet souvent "pour les entreprises" pour les technologies informatiques, on rajoute "pour les particuliers / personnel" quand la solution est différente (souvent moins coûteuse) pour les particuliers.

Dans d'autres domaines (outillage), on emploie le mot *professionnel*. (scie électrique, ...)

remarque 3: ce terme est très *marketing*. Ces technologies ont plus de 20 ans, et n'ont pas attendu des cabinets de consulting. On peut fabriquer à l'infini des acronymes en concaténant des technologies et toutes sortes de termes. *TODASN: Technical Online Discussion Authentified Social Network ...*

Comment: "Système de fichiers" ayant un sens totalement différent, je crains que cette expression soit mal interprétée par la majorité des lecteurs...

Comment: I thought translation was not allowed. Isn't this translation?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather naturally say "Solution de partage de fichiers enterprise" or "Solution de partage de fichiers pour l'entreprise", or more generally "outil collaboratif entreprise". I see Citrix Sharefile calls itself a "solution de partage et de synchronisation de fichiers d'entreprise (EFSS)".

Frenchmen seem to not be as attached to acronyms as Americans, so if you do find a convenient acronym I can guarantee that it will not be understood by most people unless directly involved in the field, and maybe not even then. The only broadly accepted acronym that I know of in the field is GED, for *Gestion Électronique de Documents*, which is not what you are looking for.

Comment: There are many enteprise file sharing solutions (ex: WebDAV shares, email, NAS, etc) but EFSS is only about the ones that work by synchronizing files. So while "Solution de partage de fichiers enterprise", "Solution de partage de fichiers pour l'entreprise", "outil collaboratif entreprise" won't do, "solution de partage et de synchronisation de fichiers d'entreprise (EFSS)" is an appropriate translation indeed, thanks! Interesting to see how they use the English acronym.

Comment: You are right that most people won't understand it, actually most native English-speaking people don't understand EFSS either. It is for use with people in this field.